# Allow directory in subdomain but not the main domain

Tags: apache, apache2, alias

I am currently running Ubuntu Server with phpMyAdmin installed.

My question is ...

How do I deny access from domain.com/phpmyadmin but allow it on sub.domain.com/phpmyadmin?

Much thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate what are you needing exactly. The question is quite unclear.

Comment: Right now I am able to access phpMyAdmin through domain.com/phpmyadmin. I don't want the entire internet to be able to get access the /phpmyadmin alias through domain.com. However, I want to be able to access /phpmyadmin through a subdomain such as example.domain.com/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Debian I set a soft link (ln) to the phpmyadmin dir that's not in the html directory. If you are using virtual domains on your install, then the example.domain.com should have a different DocumentRoot than domain.com. If you point both domains to the same DocumentRoot, then both will have access to the link to phpmyadmin.

Hope that reads as I thought it.

Comment: linking the directory wouldn't work since I had phpMyAdmin was installed using an Ubuntu package and I would have had to mess with the conf files.

However, what did work was simply using `RedirectPermanent` directive in Apache.